# Spring custom condition based validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-validator

I want to create condition based validation in spring validator.
I have one **UserDTO** class in that there are two DTO class with `@Valid` annotation.

If I pass **isPrimary** `true` then it should validate only **primaryDTO** bean and ignoring **secendoryDTO** validations.

```
public class UserDTO {
    @Valid
    private PrimaryDTO primaryDTO;
    @Valid
    private SecendoryDTO secendoryDTO;
    private boolean isPrimary;
}

public class PrimaryDTO {
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter email.")
    @Email(message = "Please enter a valid email.")
    private String email;
}

public class SecendoryDTO {
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter phone.")
    private String phone;
}
```

Please Guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your validation depends on multiple fields (eg. `isPrimary` and either `primaryDTO` or `secondaryDTO`), then the only solution is to write a custom validator on classlevel (`UserDTO`) which will implement the conditional validation itself.

For example, create an annotation:

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE})
@Constraint(validatedBy = SecondaryValidator.class)
public @interface ValidSecondary {
    String message() default "Invalid secondary";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And create a validator that only validates the `secondaryDTO` field when `isPrimary()` is `false`:

```java
@Component
public class SecondaryValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidSecondary, UserDTO> {
    private Validator validator;

    public SecondaryValidator(Validator validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(UserDTO userDTO, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (userDTO.isPrimary()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return validator.validate(userDTO.getSecondaryDTO()).isEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you can remove the `@Valid` annotation from the `secondaryDTO` field and add the `@ValidSecondary` annotation on top of your `UserDTO`:

```java
@ValidSecondary // Add this
public class UserDTO {
    @Valid
    private PrimaryDTO primaryDTO;
    private SecondaryDTO secondaryDTO; // No more @Valid
    private boolean primary;
}
```

However, in this case you'll lose any constraint violation message from within the `SecondaryDTO`, if you want to have some kind of passing through mechanism, you can add the violations to the `constraintValidatorContext` within the `isValid()` method, for example:

```java
Set<ConstraintViolation<SecondaryDTO>> violations = validator.validate(userDTO.getSecondaryDTO());
violations.forEach(violation -> constraintValidatorContext
    .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(violation.getMessage())
    .addConstraintViolation());
```

Comment: I'm getting an error Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException : SecondaryValidator.<init>()  in this class `SecondaryValidator`

Comment: @ParthSolanki You should probably add `@Autowired` to the constructor then.

Comment: I try to make the messages bubble up, but they don't seem to appear as FieldErrors in the BindingResult? Any clue?